# node-red clear context.global

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

We are working on refactoring our node-red flows. So I was trying to find a way to clear our context without having to restart node-red every time.
The thing is we are not using the conventional `global.get()` and `global.set()` to access the global context; we use a `context.global` variable, for which I cant find any reference in documentation.

So to set a new global variable we go `context.global.var1 = "value"` instead of `global.set('var1','value')`; 
And to get the value we go `var thisvalue = context.global.var1` instead of `var thisvalue = global.get('var1')`.

Also note that these two variables are not stored in the same place, `context.global` is not displayed in the Context Data Tab. And I cannot get its values with the global.get method.

So what is the difference between these two methods, and how could I clear this `context.global`, noting that I tried these methods:

```
context.global= new Object();
context.global= {};
context.global={'empty','empty'};
context.global=null;
```

Additional Info: we use version v0.20.3 of node-red

Thank you

Comment: You do know that version 1.0 shipped this week?

Comment: No, I did not know that, I will look into it, hopefully the upgrade won't affect any existing flows. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `context.global.var` is deprecated (hence why it has been removed from the doc) in favour `global.set()`, `flow.set()` or `context.set()` because this allows the use of storage plugins to make context persistent across restarts.

Storage plugins also allow you to use things this redis to share the context between multiple instances of Node-RED.

If you want to clear values in the context you need to set them to `undefined`

The other option is to write your own storage plugin that you can choose to clear how ever you want (based on what ever you use as the backing store)

Comment: Thank you, I looped through all the global variables and set them to undefined.  Works great.